# how to get Unique count from a DataFrame in case of duplicate index

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am working on a dataframe. Data in the image

Q. I want the number of shows released per year but if I'm applying count() function, it's giving me 6 instead of 3. Could anyone suggest how do I get the correct value count.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get unique value of single year, you can use

```py
count = len(df.loc[df['release_year'] == 1945, 'show_id'].unique())

# or

count = df.loc[df['release_year'] == 1945, 'show_id'].nunique()
```

To summarize unique value of dataframe by year, you can [`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) on column `show_id` first.

```py
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['show_id']).groupby('release_year').count()
```

Or use [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) on column after dropping duplicates.

```py
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['show_id'])['release_year'].value_counts()
```

Comment: It didn't work bro. I require unique counts of show_ids according to release_year.

Comment: @Arun `df['release_year'] == 1945` is just for this.

Comment: @Arun I know what you mean, stay tuned. You can `drop_duplicates` first.

Comment: @Arun Answer edited. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['show_id'].nunique().count()
```

should do the job.

Comment: it didn't work bro. I require unique counts of show_ids according to release_year